# What is the difference between Extends Application and Extends Activity in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am confused as to the difference between the two. In my application I have just used Extends Activity and the application is working perfectly, so what is the purpose of Extends Application?.

Would you use it on the first class you create in the Android application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The android.app.Application class is an optional facility for extending and storing application-global state. There are other ways of doing this, so most apps don't customize this class.

Activities however are what defines every major stage of your application. It wouldn't be possible to build an application without Activities. You will have a main Activity class and this will indeed be defined with 'extends Activity'.

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic but did you mean "It wouldn't be possible to build an application without Activities"?. I just want to be completely clear on this.

Comment: Well Activites are the building block of apps. Like pages to a web application. Any app will have at least one (although you might be able to have a Widget without one I suppose). Your app will need an entry point Activity.

Comment: So can you start classes that extend application, similar to starting Activities using intent?

Comment: You can't start an Application class no.

Answer (score 11):

Best way to see the difference would be see it's class hierarchy

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

```
java.lang.Object
  ↳ android.content.Context
      ↳ android.content.ContextWrapper
          ↳ android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
              ↳ android.app.Activity
```

And [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

```
java.lang.Object
↳   android.content.Context
   ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
       ↳    android.app.Application
```

Application is what lives till your android app process is killed. You can use this to stored Application specific data (as long as your application is alive) that may be used across various activities. Note I am not saying you should... Shared preferences may be other appropriate way to go depending on your usecase. Also just to be clear you cannot use your Application to launch your app unlike launcher Activity you give in your manifest file.

You can use your own custom Application class as follows

```
<application
    android:name="icom.osfg.test.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
    <!-- all the activities goes here -->
</application>
```

where

```
AppController extends Application
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the previous answers.

The `Application` class will be a singleton that will live as long as your app is alive.

You could initialize global components in your `Application` extended class since it will last until your process die if you don't want to handle with the usual `Activity` [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

For example, initialization of third party libraries like: Parse, CanaryLeak, Crashlytics.

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.initialize(this);
        LeakCanary.install(this);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

application is responsible for whole app

you add launcher activity in application manifest

and

in application  on create use to recreate whole app after user's Preference

Answer (score 0):

Another difference from use case point of view is classes that extend Application usually have the Application context which is required for some system services, like say a RoomDatabase class which wraps around SQLiteOpenHelper so that only one instance can be created (since they are resource heavy) So *extends Application* in this case