# The purpose of a service

Tags: java, android, android-service

From what I understood, an Android service and is nothing more than a wrapper around, respectively manager for, a thread. One can't do any lengthy operations as it is running in the context of the application's main thread (which happens to manage UI calls as well).

Could someone shed some light on the purpose of a service, if the Application class would basically cover the same functionality (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31490935)

Comment: `Application` is not at all comparable to `Service`.

Comment: Did you read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That is my question, why is it not comparable? From a functionality point of view.

Comment: `Application` is used for every process whether there is a visible `Activity` or a background `Service`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, but that is not my question. What can a service do that "application" cannot (apart from "binding") in terms of background processing?

Comment: **None** of the functionality provided by `Service` is provided by the `Application` class. They are two completely different classes which provide very separate functionality. In fact, `Application` and `Service` are used together, albeit invisibly to most uses.

Comment: What do you mean by none? Both seem to run in the same scope, both can **and need to** (for longer tasks) start and manage threads. So to reiterate my quesiton, what can a service do that "application" cannot?

Comment: If you look at the documentation for [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) you can see that they share a common subclass (`ContextWrapper`), so my previous statement is incorrect. They do both share some functionality. However, there is no overlap between the specific methods which they introduce. From a more practical standpoint, you almost never use `Application` directly in your code. On the other hand, you will often subclass `Service`.

Comment: You will then declare your service subclass in `AndroidManifest.xml`. You cannot do this with `Application`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Please dont take this as an offence, but my question were not about where in some XML document you refer to the class or how often you can do it, but **what it is you can do with a service that you cannot with "application"**.

Comment: Apparently I misunderstand your question. In fact I find the question strange since `Application` and `Service` are so completely different. The fact that you declare a service in `AndroidManifest.xml` indicates that it is a primary component in Android. This also means that it is more appropriate to compare `Service` to `Activity` since they sit at the same level of importance. In contrast, `Application` is not as important of a class. You almost never refer to it in any code (Java or XML).

Answer (score 2):

> an Android service and is nothing more than a wrapper around, respectively manager for, a thread.

No. Services do not have a separate thread by default. Services can create threads (and usually do), and some specific `Service` subclass create threads by default (e.g., `IntentService`).

> the Application class would basically cover the same functionality

The `Application` class does not cover the same functionality, any more than an `AnonymousCoward` class would. An `Application` instance does not create a thread, either. Any sort of thread manager (e.g., `ThreadPoolExecutor`) might be *used* by a service but does not *replace* a service.

Quoting [myself](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html):

> Primarily, a service exists as a flag to the operating system, indicating that you are actively delivering value to the user, and therefore Android should aim to terminate other processes — not yours — when it gets low on system RAM. Secondarily, a service provides a couple of APIs for IPC: the “command” pattern (`Intent` and `startService()`) and the “binding” pattern (`bindService()`).

An `Application` always exists in an app (an instance is created when the process is started). It does not serve as any sort of flag to the OS to indicate process importance, nor does it have any sort of IPC capability.

Comment: Funny one, quoting myself :)

Comment: @CommonsWare Thats exactly what I said, that it does not create a thread, but one needs to start a separate one, hence the service being the manager. My question is why should one use a service and not simply "Application"? Just as the "flag" you mentioned?

Comment: You say "Services do not have a separate thread by default." and my question is "separate from what"? My understanding is that a Service is spawned in a process which by default has (at least) a single main thread. Similarly, and Activity is started in a process which has a thread. In other words, anything you run on any device **does** have a thread. Whether or not other threads are spawned from there is entirely up to the app itself. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Perhaps it would be more accurate to say that a Service is a background process?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: "separate from what" -- separate from the thread that created it. "Perhaps it would be more accurate to say that a Service is a background process?" -- no, because by default, a `Service` runs in the same process as the rest of the app's components (e.g., activities).

Comment: No, I am wondering what the difference between service and "application" is. Both seem to run in the same context. @CommonsWare As to the same process, from what Bryan mentioned below it would seem a service can continue to run even if the application is stopped (which would be a distinct difference).

Comment: @user5900017: The `Application` object lives for the duration of the process. It cannot be "stopped", except by terminating the process. Terminating the process will stop *everything* in the process, which includes services.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thats what I thought, so the reference below that services can continue after the application stopped is not exactly correct? Still, I do not understand yet, what services offer what couldnt be implemented from the application object.

Comment: @user5900017: "the application stopped" is a terribly imprecise statement, which is why actual computer programmers do not use it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Call it stopped, exited, halted, whatever. That is not the point though. The application object is the instance of the actual process, correct? And once the process exits all associated "data" exits with it and this includes services. Is this correct or not? My actual question was a different one though.

Comment: @user5900017: "The application object is the instance of the actual process, correct?" -- no. `Application` is a Java object. A process is an operating system construct. "And once the process exits all associated "data" exits with it and this includes services" -- yes. This is why, for background work, it is important to use a service, to let the OS know that your app is still doing work of value to the user. Android terminates processes to free up system RAM; without a service, Android thinks that your process has low importance and is likely to kill it, even if you still have a thread going.

Comment: So the concept of services mostly exists to serve as a flag that the application should not be stopped by the system? If only the application object (respectively an associated thread) was busy that would not be "hint" enough for the system. But from a purely functional point of view, there is not such a dramatic difference between what a service can do compared to the application object?

Comment: @user5900017: As I explain in my answer, services also offer IPC capabilities. You can elect to export services, such that other apps (or the OS itself) can send them commands or bind to an exposed API. Most developers do not use those capabilities, except in cases where it's part of some higher-order functionality (e.g., `WearableListenerService` for interacting with Wear devices). For most developers, raising the process importance is the biggest impact. However, `Application` has neither of those effects (no impact on importance, no IPC capability).

Comment: @user5900017: From the standpoint of either process importance or IPC, an instance of `Application` is no different than an instance of `SomeRandomSingleton`. There are plenty of examples of objects that manage threads that do not need the capabilities of services, such as the various in-process event bus implementations (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus). They don't use custom `Application` subclasses either; they just use ordinary Java singletons.

Answer (score 0):

By default service runs in main thread but you can run it in different thread as well. Also it has its own lifecycle and it can run in both started state as well as bound state. 
Hence service is useful to do long running tasks if it runs in a background thread.

Service is not a wrapper around thread. It is having a proper lifecycle methods.

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding, the benefits of an Android `Service` are that you can run a thread that is separate from the `Application` as a whole. This allows you to continue operations of the `Service` even if the `Application` is not running.

Comment: Services do not have a separate thread by default.

Comment: @CommonsWare That is correct, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Bryan Are you saying a service will continue to run even if the application object was stopped?

Comment: @user5900017 Yes, they can run if the application is stopped. Currently I use a `WearableListenerService`, which does have separate threads by default, to communicate from an Android Wear device to the handheld device, even if the handheld app is not running.

Comment: @Bryan Thanks, WearableListenerService seems to be a special case though. Or would all services keep running after the application was stopped? My assumption was they do not, as they belong to the application process (in Unix terms). In that case a thread started by a service would be basically run forever, wouldnt it?

Comment: @user5900017 I'm not sure, `WearableListenerService` doesn't seem very special though, it directly extends `Service` and implements a class from the `NodeApi` and few `Listener` classes. And technically yes, but that would be bad practice.

Comment: I am trying to understand the implementation details, so regardless of bad practice, "technically yes" to a thread being independent from the application process? Would you have some follow-up information for that because its contrary to what I seemed to have understood. Thanks.

Comment: @user5900017 I'm speaking purely from my relatively little experience with a `Service`. But in order for the `WearableListenerService` to operate without actually opening the application, it would have to be, in some sense, separate from the application process. Therefore I do not see anything stopping you from creating a thread that could run in the background forever, though I do know that the device could kill the service, especially if it runs into an `OutOfMemoryError`.